# How to set addEventListener on innerHTML added from button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get each element reference and want to add event listener on each item, but when I add HTML using innerHTML, I am not able to use it outside anywhere. How can I use it everywhere and instead of just event listener, how can I reference it also?
I know there are other ways to add HTML using javascript, but for now, I want to do it with innerHTML.

```js
const mybtn = document.getElementById('maybe');
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

mybtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        parent.innerHTML = `<div>
          <h1 id="one" class="one">Hello 1</h1>
          <h1 class="two">Hello 2</h1>
          <h1 class="three">Hello 3</h1>
          <h1 class="four">Hello 4</h1>
        </div>`
});

const one = document.getElementById('one');
one.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert('one');
});
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<button id="maybe">Set</button>
```

Comment: One More Problem Is That You Need To Set The Event Listeners After The User Has Clicked The Button, because till then the element is not defined.

Comment: I think we're missing an overall picture if what needs to be done . The question makes perfect sense to you, maybe less so to readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add the eventListener to elements which are yet to be created. As currently your elements are only added to parent on buttonClick of `myBtn`.

If you add the event listener when the elements are created then your code will work.

```js
const mybtn = document.getElementById("maybe");
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");

mybtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  parent.innerHTML = `<div>
              <h1 class="one">Hello 1</h1>
              <h1 class="two">Hello 2</h1>
              <h1 class="three">Hello 3</h1>
              <h1 class="four">Hello 4</h1>
            </div>`;
  const one = document.querySelector(".one");
  one.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    alert("one");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<button id="maybe">Set</button>
```

Comment: but if I am just referencing something, it will happen on button click? like some if statements

Comment: @Leith JavaScript runs synchronously. You are attempting to get the element `const one = document.getElementById('one');` on the first run of the JS. As it does not yet exist it will not work. You can only get the element once it exists. I suggest you explain more clearly what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean = perhaps by adding that code to your question? It's not really clear what you mean. @Leith

Comment: @DanielJ, this was my first part of the question, there is another question after this, so should I ask in another post or edit the same question? it is a little different question from this, and thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword that you would want to google for is `event delegation`.

To understand the issue you are facing, you will need to understand the executing order of your code.

```
mybtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        parent.innerHTML = `<div>
          <h1 class="one">Hello 1</h1>
          <h1 class="two">Hello 2</h1>
          <h1 class="three">Hello 3</h1>
          <h1 class="four">Hello 4</h1>
        </div>`
});

const one = document.querySelector('.one');
one.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert('one');
});
```

In your code, you are adding a `click` event on `mybtn` that will  set the `innerHTML` of another HTML element. In addition to that, you also select other elements by className `.one` and then add `click` event to it. The question is, which one happens first? Your `innerHTML` set or `querySelector`?

And the answer is the `querySelector`.

If you look into the dev tools and put up some checkpoint, you will see that `innerHTML` line only run when you actually clicking the button, and might be way after the `querySelector`. So by the time the `querySelector` runs, your HTML page doesn't even know about any elements that have the class `.one`.

So, how would you deal with these dynamically generated elements?

### Set the handler after you create the element (IMO, bad way)

You would simply move your click handler to after the `innerHTML` set.

```
mybtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        parent.innerHTML = `<div>
          <h1 class="one">Hello 1</h1>
          <h1 class="two">Hello 2</h1>
          <h1 class="three">Hello 3</h1>
          <h1 class="four">Hello 4</h1>
        </div>`
    const one = document.querySelector('.one');
    one.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        alert('one');
    });
});
```

This will ensure that your `querySelector` can target the elements you are looking for

### Set up event delegation (IMO, better way)

So the problem with the above one is that, you will have to rerun the `click` handler whenever you `click` the button. With a small app, this is acceptable. However, this is still not a good practice.

Since JS event will bubble up to the parent element, you don't need to target the exact element to add the events. Instead, you can target the parent.

Your code will look something like this

```
mybtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        parent.innerHTML = `<div>
          <h1 class="one">Hello 1</h1>
          <h1 class="two">Hello 2</h1>
          <h1 class="three">Hello 3</h1>
          <h1 class="four">Hello 4</h1>
        </div>`
});

parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('one')) {
        alert('one');
    }
}
```

What the code is doing is:

- add the `click` event to the parent element - as we know, the event will be bubbling up from the actual `.one` element to `parent` element, this will be fired when `.one` is `click`
- we use `e` (the `click` event) to retrieve `e.target`, which is the element that actual trigger the event
- we then check whether that is the element that we are looking for.

You can read more about it [here](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: does the event delegation only works on event listeners?

Comment: I haven't encountered any other event delegation for any other things. I think it's only being used for event listeners

Comment: how can I do something like document.querySelectorAll(".allitems"); using event delegation? and add event listners using for each item?

Comment: let cbox = document.querySelectorAll(".item-thumb");
     cbox.forEach(box => {
     box.addEventListener('click', () => {
         alert('clicked');
     });

Comment: it depends on your HTML tree. If you read through the link that I included, the event delegation is basically the act of "move the event handler from children element to parent element". From there, you can do whatever you want with the rest of your code.

Comment: it does seems like you are trying to add an event handler to all element with className `.item-thumb`, then my example code would work for you since it's checking `classList` (to container `one` in my example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243758/discussion-between-tree-nguyen-and-leith).